# *controller*.js.coffee and *controller*.css.sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see these files are created when I generate a new controller. When are these used? I see that Rails will compile a single js/css file, so I'm guessing they are not only used for a particular controller. Is it just simply to allow developers to break up their code by contoller rather than a simple HUGE file for the entire app? Just don't know whether I need/ will use them or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought is correct. They are used for keeping css and js that's specific to your controller separate as you develop. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets) is some more information on controller specific assets (js and css). You can turn off the automatic generation of assets for a controller by setting the following in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.assets false
end
```